# How to set the leftview location on UITextfield to be close to the placehoder text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am using UITextfield as a search field to allow users filtering the content. When a user open the UI, the UITextField will show a placeholder message "search" in the center of the textfield. I want to add a leftview icon right before the placeholder text(see below code). The leftwiew icon will be shown on the very left of the text field. I want to place it right before the text. How can I find the right position for it?

```
searchText.placeholder = "Search"
    searchText.leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "cion_03.png"))
    searchText.leftView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    searchText.leftViewMode = .Always
```

Comment: what is the issue with ur current code ? post a screenshot that explains the issue.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet, for this level of customization, is to subclass `UITextField`. You will be able to modify the frame of the placeholder text, to modify its position.

You should override `placeholderRectForBounds:`. Once that is changed, you might find that you will need to override `textRectForBounds:` to match the placeholder text position.

I've seen this approach used successfully, to accommodate certain fonts.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to set frame for view. Try to set proper `x` position to your'e image.

```
let icon = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "cion_03"))
icon.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, icon.image.size.width+10.0, icon.image.size.height);
icon.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
self.textField.leftView = icon;
self.textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a day trying to do this using the UITextField subclass. Got it mostly working but I also needed to change the text alignment from centered to left-aligned when editing. I ended up solving this by constraining an image view to the front of the text field and it worked great. I was even able to animate them back and forth and everything.